# How to reset whole a appearance (Gnome)?

Tags: gnome, 18.10, lts, appearance

I installed many different themes and icons. Now I want to bring the appearance of the desktop and the login window as it was before. How to do it?

Comment: `sudo dconf reset -f /` will do somewhat youare looking for but login window, it depends how you changed..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have used Gnome Tweaks. To reset everything you have made, open the gnome tweaks, and select from the menu:

> Reset to Defaults

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? Where is the "Reset to Defaults" option?

Comment: It is in the top "hamburger" menu (the three horizontal lines in the middle of the top bar), first option.